# changing colour of text dependent on time value php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, function

I want to try get a traffic light colour scheme with my time text where if the time is between 0.0000 and 10.0000 the text if green if between 10.0100 and 15.0000 the text is orange and between 15.0100 and 20.0000 then its red i cant get my function to run i may be missing something but im not sure what.

currently the mysql query returns result as 14.6263 with this value constantly changing

my current code is :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<title>time stats</title>

<style>
body {
background-color: black;
}
.box1 {
width: 300px;
height: 400px;
border: 15px solid yellow;
padding: 15px;
margin: 15px;
display: inline-block;
color: white;
font-size:40px;
color: lime;

.container  {
text-align: center;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="box1">
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','test');
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="select avg(time_format(delivery_avg,'%i:%s')) as time_avg from test.del where location = 'yellow'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<thead>
<th>time Average</th>
</thead>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['time_avg'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</div>
  function updatecolor() {
        //console.log('function called');
        {
if ($box1.td < 10)
    return '#00FF00';
else if ($box1.td >= 11 && $box1.td<= 15)
    return = '#FFA500';
else if ($box1.td >= 16 && $box1.td<= 20)
    return = '#ff0000';
}
        });

    }
    var updateInterval = setInterval(updatecolor, 1000);
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your function looks like it's missing the surrounding `<?php` and `?>` tags...

Comment: And you're not calling the function `changeColor` anywhere...

Comment: how can even it work ?

Comment: Also, you're using `$box` as function parameter, which is never used. `$td` in your function is useless. `return = '#ff0000';` is not valid.

Comment: so i have updated my code to include a function call but still seem to have the same issue it doesnt run the code or i have written it wrong

Comment: So, to clear things up: do you want your function to be a `PHP` function or a `Javascript ` function?

Comment: i dont mind on what type of function it is a just want to be able to change the colour of the text dependent on what value is displaying in box 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little function that will return your colors depending on the `$valueToCheck` parameter of the function:

```
<?php
function addColor($valueToCheck) {
    {
        if ($valueToCheck <= 10) {
            return '#00FF00';
        } else if ($valueToCheck >= 11 && $valueToCheck <= 15) {
            return '#FFA500';
        } else if ($valueToCheck >= 16 && $valueToCheck <= 20) {
            return '#ff0000';
        }
    };
}
?>
```

Wrapped it in `<?php ?>` tags, since it's a PHP function.

Use it in your HTML like so:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td style=\"color:" . addColor($row['time_avg']) . "\">";
  echo $row['time_avg'];
  echo "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

As for your code:

`return = '#FFA500';` is not valid, remove the `=`.

If `$box1` were available:

```
if ($box1.td < 10)
    return '#00FF00';
else if ($box1.td >= 11 && $box1.td<= 15)
```

What about `10`? You never check for `10>x>11`.

Comment: so after updating the code to try this it the page gives me an error 500 where i have updated the mysql part

Comment: is it possible that i could just run the script every time the page the page loads with something like 
    
<script type="text/javascript">
     function setClass($td) {
      {
        if ($td <= 10) {
            return '#00FF00';
        } else if ($td >= 11 && $td <= 15) {
            return '#FFA500';
        } else if ($td >= 16 && $td <= 20) {
            return '#ff0000';
        }
    };
    }
                window.onload = setClass;
        </script>

Comment: Changed the code, renamed the function to `addColor`, since it's more fitting. I also removed a `<?php` from the `while`-loop

Comment: where it has value to check should i leave that or change it to $td as that what needs changing ?

Comment: Hi Sorry to bring the question back up how have you defined value to check so that it changes the colour of text im trying to use the same function to change the colour of a html cell border but cant get it to work

Comment: Not sure if I get your question right, do you mean this: `echo "<td style=\"color:" . addColor($row['time_avg']) . "\">";` Here it sets the color to the value returned by the function. If you want to change the border-color of the `td` you should use `echo "<td style=\"border-color:" . addColor($row['time_avg']) . "\">";`

Comment: thank you how could i implement this so that it would change the border of a cell where the function looks like the below

Comment: Code in comments is horrible to read, I suggest you create a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48870078/change-the-colour-of-a-cell-border-using-a-java-script-function

this containts my code for the table how can i implement your idea to change the cell border the same way the text changed?